# How would I test if a particular object is entirely within another object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision

I don't want to just test if an object has collided with another object but rather test if the entire object (which is rectangular like) is completely located within another object (which is circular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's a built-in way to do this in ActionScript. One way this could be achieved is to create points at the corners of the object and use hitTestPoint to check if each is within the object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up realising that there isn't any built in way, I did manage to get around it in the end though.